# how can run django on centos using wsgi

Tags: python, django, apache, wsgi, centos6

I try 2 way to config wsgi to use Django for my site.
my root project file is in /var/run/myApp.
this is my wsgi.py :

```
import os
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'myApp.settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

1.I install everything that need to run Django on apache and using centos as OS. I use [this](https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi) site to run wsgi.I use this command to setup my server :

```
mod_wsgi-express setup-server wsgi.py --port=80 --user test --group test --server-root=/var/run/myApp/mod_wsgi-express-80
```

after that I run this command and everything is fine:

```
/var/run/myApp/mod_wsgi-express-80/apachectl start
```

but when I browse my site I get error `500 : Internal Server Error`

2.I also already try another way to config apache conf file but I get this error in error_log of apache :

```
" Target WSGI script not found or unable to stat: /run "
```

and this is what I write in httpd.conf:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess mySite user=test group=test
WSGIProcessGroup mySite

<VirtualHost *:80>
    WSGIScriptAlias / run/myApp/my_App/wsgi.py
    <Directory run/myApp/my_App>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

what is problem? thanks.

Comment: Seems quite obvious: your path is `/var/run/myApp...` but your httpd.conf only has `run/myApp...`.

Comment: I try /var/run/myApp... but no success

Comment: 500: Internal server error means there are something wrong with your code. Please try to run this application as standalone. If its works fine then run with apache. Also check `apache_error.log` for the errors in wsgi script.

Comment: I test my app before put it on apache and it work fine. when I try method #1 I get no error in log file

Comment: Check apache error log.

Comment: ImportError: Could not import settings 'myApp.settings'

Comment: should I use sys.path.append("some path") in my wsgi file ?

Comment: Terrible question quality, -1

Answer (score 2):

If using Django, you are better off using the mod_wsgi express integration for Django.

Thus, add `'mod_wsgi.server'` to `INSTALLED_APPS` in Django `settings.py`.

Then use `--setup-only` option to the `runmodwsgi` management command:

```
python manage.py runmodwsgi --setup-only --port=80 --user test --group test --server-root=/var/run/myApp/mod_wsgi-express-80
```

This is instead of using `mod_wsgi-express setup-server`.

You can then use:

```
/var/run/myApp/mod_wsgi-express-80/apachectl start
```

as root.

By using the `runmodwsgi` management command, mod_wsgi express will factor in the Django static files directory and add it to the generated Apache configuration automatically.

In using static files, just remember to run:

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

so that any static files are copied to the `STATIC_ROOT` directory you specified in the Django `settings.py` file.

In using the management command, mod_wsgi express should also correctly setup the top level directory for Django as the home directory for the application and ensure the module search path is set appropriately so that your project modules are found.