# Django with mod_wsgi-express and Apache displays Apache test page instead of site home page

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

I'm trying to setup a Django based website on a CentOS 6.7 Linux PaaS server VM.

I've installed Python 2.7.8 in a virtualenv.

I'm using Apache 2.2.15 (installed using yum), Django 1.7 (installed using pip2.7) and mod_wsgi-express version 4.4.21 (that I compiled from source).

I've followed the instructions at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mod_wsgi
and am at a point where this command, issued at the Django project root directory, works for me:

```
(vishwaas_env)$sudo python manage.py runmodwsgi  --host=0.0.0.0 --port=80 --user apache --group apache --server-root=/home/syt_admin/projects/vishwaas/www
```

I'm able to point my browser to the public ip address of the VM and connect to my site. The error_log located in my server-root directory shows normal operation:

```
[Thu Dec 03 10:48:22 2015] [notice] Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) mod_wsgi/4.4.21 Python/2.7.8 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

However, since I would like to start this as a background task, I followed Graham's answer to this question:

[how can run django on centos using wsgi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24760872/how-can-run-django-on-centos-using-wsgi)

I've setup the server configs:

```
(vishwaas_env)$ python manage.py runmodwsgi --setup-only --host=0.0.0.0 --port=80 --user apache --group apache --server-root=/home/syt_admin/projects/vishwaas/www
```

and started the apachectl script in the server-root directory

```
(vishwaas_env)$ sudo apachectl start
```

But this time, pointing the browser to the same ip address displays the Apache 2 Test page. Also, this time, the error_log that contains messages is the one at
/var/log/httpd/error_log

```
[Thu Dec 03 10:50:52 2015] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper:   /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Thu Dec 03 10:50:52 2015] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Thu Dec 03 10:50:52 2015] [notice] Digest: done
[Thu Dec 03 10:50:52 2015] [notice] Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) DAV/2 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Dec 03 10:51:03 2015] [error] [client <ip address>] Directory index forbidden by Options directive: /var/www/html/
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Just realized my mistake.

$sudo apachectl start

was executing the script at /usr/sbin/apachectl

and not the one in my local directory.

$sudo ./apachectl start

invoked the one with the correct configs. I need to figure out what is missing in my path definition.